# How can I sync Google Calendar and Outlook 2013?

Tags: google-calendar, outlook

I downloaded Google Apps Sync and logged in. 
Then it says that the sync is supported only for business and educational users.

I'm aware of a software called iCal4OL (recommended in [this article](http://email.about.com/od/googlecalendartips/qt/Sync_Outlook_Google_Calendar_and_iPhone_Calendar.htm) re. syncing Outlook, Google Calendar and iPhone calendar). However, it is available only for 14 days trial period.

Is there any other way to sync them?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/561660/how-can-i-sync-my-outlook-calendar-with-google-calendar-preferably-using-a-free and/or http://superuser.com/questions/449726/outlook-2013-with-google-activesync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer [Sync2](http://sync2.com) Here is article about Outlook synchronization solutions on [Guardian](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/askjack/2011/jun/30/ask-jack-synchronise-outlook-two-computers?INTCMP=SRCH). Full solution list can be found on syncdroid.net.
Most popular are:
Sync2, CompanionLink, gSyncit

Answer (score -1):

I would just open your google calendar as an internet calendar in outlook.
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/18353/view-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-2010/

Answer (score -2):

Copy both unifiedlogin.dll and gsync32.dll from C:\Program Files\Google\Google Apps Sync to C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14 or Office15

Comment: Can you expand on that? Why will this solve the problem?